# Bidirectional communication with AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges

Tags: macos, authorization, pipe, file-descriptor

I need to execute a helper tool with [AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges), send some data to its stdin, and read a reply on stdout. I can successfully execute the helper tool and read its stdout via the communicationsPipe, but if I write to its stdin I have to close the file descriptor to send an EOF, otherwise the helper tool waits indefinitely. Since all that's returned is a file descriptor opened for reading and writing, how do I just close the write end, but keep the read end open?

Answer (score 0):

You could write an EOF (see stdin.h define of EOF) to the stdin.  That should do it.  You could also communicate with your helper tool via named pipes or sockets, though the helper tool would have to support that.